# Error modal en formulario

Tags: php, html, modal

Hace nada he descubierto la existencia de los modales, y me pareció muy interesante para añadirlo a la web. Me fijé en el código de w3schools, lo copié a mi código y, sí, aparece, pero durante 1 segundo y luego desaparece, mostrando una página en blanco.
Me gustaría añadir el modal cuando se presione el botón "Enviar", que aparezca la ventanita, y cuando se cierre se envíen los datos y se resetée el formulario.
He estado buscando varias horas, pero no encuentro nada, o me lío, o no sé cómo hacerlo.

Mando el código que tengo en varios archivos.

**Index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Formulario</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="form">
            <form action="guardar.php" method="POST">
                <p>Nombre</p>
                <label for="nombre">Su nombre</label>
                <br><br>
                <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" required>
                <p>Correo</p>
                <label for="correo">Direccion De Correo</label>
                <br><br>
                <input type="email" name="correo" placeholder="ejemplo@ejemplo.com" required>
                <p>Mensaje</p>
                <label for="mensaje">Su Mensaje</label>
                <br><br>
                <textarea name="mensaje" placeholder="Mensaje" required></textarea>
                <br>
                <br>
                <button id="myBtn" class="button" input type="submit" value="Enviar">Enviar</button>

            </form>
        </div>

        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal">

        <!-- Modal content -->
         <div class="modal-content">
           <span class="close">&times;</span>
           <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
         </div>

</div>
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**guardar.php:**

```
<?php
    //conectamos Con el servidor
    $host="localhost";
    $user="root";
    $pass="";
    $db="prueba";

    $con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db) or die ("Problemas al conectar");
    mysqli_select_db($con,$db) or die ("Problemas al conectar con la base de datos");

    //recuperar las variables
    $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
    $correo=$_POST['correo'];
    $mensaje=$_POST['mensaje'];

    //Hacer secuencia sql
    $sql="INSERT INTO datos (nombre, correo, mensaje) VALUES ('{$nombre}','{$correo}','{$mensaje}')";

    //ejecutamos la sentencia de sql
    $ejecutar=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    //verificamos la ejecucion
    if($ejecutar){

    echo"Datos Guardados Correctamente<br><a href='index.html'>Volver</a>";

    }else{

    echo "Hubo Algun Error";

    }
```

?>

Supongo que el problema principalmente estará en "guardar.php" en el

```
if($ejecutar){

        echo"Datos Guardados Correctamente<br><a href='index.html'>Volver</a>";


    }else{
        echo"Hubo Algun Error";
    }
```

El problema es que no sé qué poner en el "if" si sale bien.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cuando te refieres a:

> '*pero durante 1 segundo y luego desaparece*'

se debe al botón de tipo submit que lleva a la dirección web indicada en el campo action del formulario. Para lo que desea hacer; recomiendo que utilices AJAX para prevenir el comportamiento por defecto del botón.

En el código te comenté los cambio que realice

**Index.html:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Formulario</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Utilizamos jQuery para simplificar el uso de AJAX -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="form">
    <!-- Eliminamos el action y le damos un id al formulario -->
      <form method="POST" id="formulario" name="formulario" role="form">
        <p>Nombre</p><label for="nombre">Su nombre</label>
        <br><br>
        <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" required>
        <p>Correo</p><label for="correo">Direccion De Correo</label>
        <br><br>
        <input type="email" name="correo" placeholder="ejemplo@ejemplo.com" required>
        <p>Mensaje</p>
        <label for="mensaje">Su Mensaje</label>
        <br><br>
        <textarea name="mensaje" placeholder="Mensaje" required></textarea>
        <br><br>
        <button id="myBtn" class="button" input type="submit" value="Enviar">Enviar</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <!-- Le asignamos un id al elemento p el cual será donde se mostrará el resultado de AJAX -->
      <p id="resultado"></p>
    </div>
    <script>
    // Se selecciona el id del formulario
      $('#formulario').submit(function(event) {
        // Obtenemos todos los datos
        var parametros = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
          // Lo enviamos mediante POST
          type: "POST",
          // A la URL
          url: "guardar.php",
          // Le pasamos los datos del formulario
          data: parametros,
          success: function(data) {
            // Abrimos el modal
            $("#myModal").modal("show");
            // Mostramos el resultado de la URL
            $('#resultado').html(data);
            // Reseteamos el formulario
            document.getElementById("formulario").reset();
          }
        });
        // Prevenimos que el botón submit recargue la página
        event.preventDefault();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**guardar.php:**

```html
<?php
  //conectamos Con el servidor
  $host="localhost";
  $user="root";
  $pass="";
  $db="prueba";

  $con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db) or die ("Problemas al conectar");
  mysqli_select_db($con,$db) or die ("Problemas al conectar con la base de datos");

  //recuperar las variables
  $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
  $correo=$_POST['correo'];
  $mensaje=$_POST['mensaje'];

  //Hacer secuencia sql
  $sql="INSERT INTO datos (nombre, correo, mensaje) VALUES ('{$nombre}','{$correo}','{$mensaje}')";

  //ejecutamos la sentencia de sql
  $ejecutar=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

  //verificamos la ejecucion
  if($ejecutar){
    echo"Datos Guardados Correctamente<br><a href='index.html'>Volver</a>";
  } else {
    echo "Hubo Algun Error";
  }
?>
```

Comment: ¡Me funcionó! ¡Muchas gracias! Estaba perdidísima con este tema porque nunca me había metido con scripts y demás... ¡Pero me has sido de mucha ayuda! ¡Gracias!